# Server Error in Application Kentico 7.31

Tags: kentico

When I click tools in CMSDesk I get an "Server Error in Application" errir
I was able to solve this error in Kentico 7.0 as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202685/server-error-in-kenticocms-application-clicking-on-tools-in-cms-desk-in-kent)

However i now have the same error in a 7.31 installation.

The event log is

```
Event ID: 77 
Event type: Error 
Event time: 5/2/2013 10:27:08 PM 
Source: Application_Error 
Event code: EXCEPTION 
User ID: 53 
User name: administrator 
IP address: ::1 

Description: Message: Multiple controls with the same ID 'bRecentDocs' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs. 
Stack Trace: 
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
at CMS.ExtendedControls.ScrollPanel.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 

includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Site name: new2 
Machine name: RN7 
Event URL: /KenticoCMS7E/CMSModules/MyDesk/mainMenu.aspx 
URL referrer: http://localhost/KenticoCMS7E/CMSModules/MyDesk/Default.aspx 
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
```

I know that the problem is in the database because if I switch to a different database there is no problem.

[Update]
If I run the application the last piece of code that I can see in the debugger before the crash is in 
In CMSAdminControls_UI_UniMenu_UniMenu

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Register scripts
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptHelper.RegisterJQuery(Page);
        ScriptHelper.RegisterScriptFile(Page, "~/CMSAdminControls/UI/UniMenu/UniMenu.js");

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Kentico support confirm the problem is in the database and are sending me a fix.

Comment: Hi, Kristen G. Have you tried to solve the problem by yourself? E.g. debug the application?

Comment: Thanks Rocky, good idea. I updated the question with the findings.

Comment: Go to CMS Site Manager -> Development -> Modules. Edit 'Tools' and go to User interface tab. Examine all nodes - Look at their code names and check if some of them isn't equal to 'RecentDocs'. This node is by default under 'My Desk' module under Documents & Objects node so I don't know why tools tab tries to load it.

Comment: Horray! Please write this as the answer!  I had the same problem under 'My Desk' . When I followed your instructions I found several duplicate entries there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to CMS Site Manager -> Development -> Modules. Edit 'Tools' and go to User interface tab. Examine all nodes - Look at their code names and check if some of them isn't equal to 'RecentDocs'. This node is by default under 'My Desk' module under Documents & Objects node so I don't know why tools tab tries to load it.